# Best practices for manage countries in a bbdd

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to create a database with all the countries of the world in every language, but i don't know what is the best way to do it.
Maybe creating a table with an `idCountry`, and in each column, the country name in different languages? Like `nameEN`, `nameES`
Or maybe creating one table to each language naming the table something like `countriesEN` , `countriesES` ...

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Neither. A normalized approach would be best. I wouldn't attempt this until I was confident that I had a fairly decent grasp of what normalization is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the essential requirements are as follows (although you could argue about whether or not surrogate keys are necessary or appropriate...):

You need to start with a core a language. This could be Klingon, if you like, but let's use English...

```
country (country_id*,common_name_of_country_in_english)

language (language_id*,name_of_language_in_english)

country_in_language(country_id*,language_id*,name_of_country_in_language)

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```

Incidentally, there are approximately 250 countries in the world (maybe a new one by the end of today), and 7,000 languages, so you're going to be busy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to consider a few aspects like maintanability, performance, and effort you need to create the database. If it's going to be a rather big system, I would create a Language, Country and CountryName table. It could look somewhat like this:

```
Country
id

Language
id
key
name

CountryName
id
name
Country_id
Language_id
```

Like this you'd avoid duplication and have a fully [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) database.

Comment: Perhaps a consequence of brevity, but this isn't quite right.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the essential thing, you're right ;-)

Comment: Unless `id` in the country the table refers to the ISO3166 code, then I'd say it's still not quite right. I'll elaborate...